# Error loading workspace: err: exit status 1: stderr: go: updates to go.sum needed, disabled by -mod=readonly : packages.Load error

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode and `vscode-go` to develop the Go application,but, sometime, I got this error, and can't jump to the code definination

How can I get past this error message and get back all gopls features?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As explained in [`golang/vscode-go` issue 1229](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/1229):

> The error message indicates the go.mod file is incomplete and needs update.
>
> Check the "`PROBLEMS`" view (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> `> "Problems: Focus On Problems View`" ), find the error-level problem (probably in the `go.mod` file), and either choose the Quick Fix or check the light bulb.
>
> Or, simply open the `go.mod` file and run '`go mod tidy`' using the code lens at the top of the file.

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/4999471/110490101-fc008980-80bd-11eb-9b7d-f07e35d46f1a.png]

Obviously, make sure you are using the latest versions (of Go, VSCode and vscode-go, as well as gopls)